# Ruby on Rails Hartl Tutorial Chapter 10.1.3 Something wrong with my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i'm working through Hartl. Ive got to the micro posts section in Chapter 10 but I'm generating 9 fails which I don't understand!

```
Failures:

  1) Hotel 
     Failure/Error: it {should be_valid}
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Hotel user 
     Failure/Error: its(:user) { should == user }
       expected: #<User id: 211, name: "Person 80", email: "person_78@example.com", created_at: "2013-04-26 22:09:22", updated_at: "2013-04-26 22:09:22", password_digest: "$2a$04$ofUpcvsd84qDWTXG131PYedxXdTy2nPzTME/Gf5rc8c0...", remember_token: "wsF59SbMlKni1mqKLhFX0A", admin: false>
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/hotel_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's my hotel_spec.rb file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Hotel do
  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  before {@hotel = user.hotels.build(title: "Hilton", room_description: "Biiiiig Room",include_breakfast: "false", price: 566.6, adress:"Smolnaya")}

    subject(@hotel)

    it {should respond_to(:title)}
    it {should respond_to(:room_description)}
    it {should respond_to(:include_breakfast)}
    it {should respond_to(:price)}
    it {should respond_to(:adress)}
    it {should respond_to(:user_id)}
    it {should respond_to(:user)}

    its(:user) { should == user }

    it {should be_valid}

    describe "accesible attributes" do
      it "should not allow access to user_id" do
        expect do
          Hotel.new(user_id: user.id)
        end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
      end
    end

    describe "when user_id is not present" do
      before {@hotel.user_id = nil}
      it {should_not be_valid}
    end

end
```

my hotel.rb file

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :adress, :include_breakfast, :price, :room_description, :title
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

where I made a mistake?Any ideas and solutions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subject { @hotel }
```

Braces, not parentheses.
`subject` expects a code block ([i.e. similar to `do ... end`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587264/do-end-vs-curly-braces-for-blocks-in-ruby)), not arguments.

[A little off-topic, but it may be helpful to follow the convention of including white space within the braces.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238864/ruby-whitespace-is-a-1-better-than-a-1)

Comment: Thank you so much! Stupid error, I should stop writing a code at night

Answer (score 1):

@Sunxperous answer seems to be correct - I would recommend you use the [thoughtbot shoulda gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) to make your tests even simpler. Also use FactoryGirl to create your hotel model. With the gem you rspec could look like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Hotel do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
  subject(:hotel) { FactoryGirl.create :hotel, user: user }

  it { should be_valid } # a valid factory is very important

  it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of :user_id }
  it { should validates_presence_of :user }
  it { should belong_to :user }

  it {should respond_to(:title)}
  it {should respond_to(:room_description)}
  it {should respond_to(:include_breakfast)}
  it {should respond_to(:price)}
  it {should respond_to(:adress)}
  it {should respond_to(:user_id)}
  it {should respond_to(:user)}

end
```

Comment: But I already use FactoryGirl...and thank's for shoulda gem? very helpful